# Is 'subject' in 'is subject to considerable debate' a verb or a noun?

Tags: phrases, verbs, nouns, parts-of-speech

Every once in a while I stumble upon this phrase:

> ... is subject to considerable debate

Examples are easily found on the web, for instance:

> In the context of suspected cognitive disorders, the validity of memory complaints is subject to considerable debate

However, this phrase does not seem grammatically correct to me. I could expect it to be:

> ... is a subject for considerable debate

in which case 'subject' is a noun, or:

> ... is subjected to considerable debate

where 'subject' is a verb in past participle.

Still, both alternatives are much less common, judging by the number of occurrences in Google, than the original phrase. So here are the questions:

1. Is this phrase appropriate for formal writing?
2. Is it appropriate for less formal conversation?
3. Finally, is 'subject' in this phrase a noun or verb?

   1. Where should I put the stress when I read the phrase aloud?

Comment: It's neither: it's an adjective, reflecting in its sense the Latin passive participle from which the word (in all three senses) is derived.

Comment: Which is to say that in English this _subject_ is a ***Predicate** Adjective*, the main predicate in the verb phrase _is subject to considerable debate_. As a predicate adjective, it requires an auxiliary _be_ (that's the _is_), and it is intransitive (so it requires a preposition _to_ marking any object). The combination has become iconic in lawyerly language, which means we're stuck with it forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the comments posted to the original question, I can assume the whole answer, which is:

1. Yes, it is appropriate for formal writing.
2. No, it probably won't fit in a casual informal conversation.
3. 'subject' is an adjective, therefore its form is perfectly correct.

   1. The stress should be on the first syllable as ['sʌbʤekt].